# How to update TinyMCE editor content in Angular after @Input variable changed?

Tags: angular, initialization, tinymce

I have an `Angular` component to show the form with `TinyMCE` editor, but the TinyMCE editor is a different component. Here is the code:

blog-edit.component.ts:

```
export class BlogEditComponent implements OnInit {
  private data = {};

  constructor(
    private blogService: BlogService,
    private location: Location) {
      if (this.location.path().match(/^\/blog\/edit\/(\d+)$/) ) {
        const id = this.location.path().replace(/^\/blog\/edit\/(\d+)$/, '$1');
        this.loadToEdit( Number(id) );
      }
  }

  loadToEdit(id: number) {
    this.blogService.getOne(id).subscribe(response => {
      const data = response.json();

      // ... here do some data conversion process

      // publish loaded and parsed datas
      this.data = data;

    }, error => {
      // ...
    });
  }
}
```

blog-edit.component.html

```
<app-tinymce-editor elementId="_content" [content]="data.content"
  (editorContentChange)="tinyMcePreviewUpdater($event)"></app-tinymce-editor>
```

tinymce-editor.component.ts:

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter,
         AfterViewInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import 'tinymce';
import 'tinymce/themes/modern';
// plugins
import 'tinymce/plugins/table';

declare let tinymce: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tinymce-editor',
  templateUrl: './tinymce-editor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tinymce-editor.component.css']
})
export class TinymceEditorComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() elementId: string;
  @Input() content: string;
  @Output() editorContentChange = new EventEmitter();

  editor: any;
  opions = {
    selector: undefined,
    setup: undefined,
    // other tinymce init options
  };

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.options.selector = '#' + this.elementId;
    this.options.setup = editor => {
      this.editor = editor;
      this.editor.on('keyup change', () => {
        this.editorContentChange.emit( editor.getContent() );
      });
    };

    tinymce.init(this.options);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    tinymce.remove(this.editor);
  }

}
```

tinymce-editor.component.html

```
<textarea id="{{ elementId }}" name="{{ elementId }}"></textarea>
```

Now the problem is: the TinyMCE initialized first, and data loaded after, and the editor's content doesn't updated.

How can I update editor's content when the `content` variable is cahnged in the `tinymce-editor.component.ts` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you initialize TinyMCE on each `textarea` before each `textarea` has its content then TinyMCE won't auto-magically go back and update itself when the `textarea` gets updated with content - TinyMCE just does not work that way.

You could use TinyMCE APIs (e.g. `setContent()`)

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editor/#setcontent) to update the editor's

...to inject the content once you get the data.  Alternatively you could delay initializing TinyMCE until after the data is fetched into each `textarea`.

Neither approach is better/worse - there are certainly multiple ways to solve this and they all work if implemented appropriately.

Comment: The question is how can I detect when the `content` variable is updated and I need to run the `setContent()` method?

Comment: Does your `loadToEdit` function's success handler get called after the data is returned?  Perhaps that is when you should update TinyMCE?

Comment: but that is out of my `tinymce-editor.component.ts`, if I move the tinymce update logic to there, that means I need to move the init function too... and the spearated component lose his meaning at this point... but you gave me an idea to use `editor` variable with `EventEmitter`

Comment: that wasn't a working idea so this isn't a right way :(